# Prove $\sqrt{a_{1}a_{n}}\leq\sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdot...\cdot a_{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let {$a_{n}$} be an arithmetic sequence with positive terms.
Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $$\sqrt{a_{1}a_{n}}\leq\sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdot...\cdot a_{n}}$$
When proving that using induction, induction step would be if it is true for some n,
we show that $$\sqrt{a_{1}a_{n}a_{n+1}}\leq\sqrt[n+1]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdot...\cdot a_{n}a_{n+1}}$$ or
$$\sqrt{a_{1}a_{n+1}}\leq\sqrt[n+1]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdot...\cdot a_{n}a_{n+1}}$$ and why?
Also solutions for this problem are appreciated.

Comment: Only your last inequation is valid as an induction step.

Comment: @talbi: why $a_{n+2}$ ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oops, you are correct - it's fine how it is. My bad!

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought so but my question is why is that

Comment: By arithmetic sequence do you mean the terms are of the form $a_j=a+jd$ for some $a,d$?

Comment: @Forester In my book, no; but I am asking what OP means by the phrase "arithmetic sequence", I have never heard of it before.

Comment: $\sqrt{a_1a_na_{n+1}}$ does not have the same shape as the initial inequality and is of no use.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, arithmetic sequence/progression. What are other names for it?

Comment: Thanks, "arith. progression" I knew, but not "arith. sequence". And as rudgns55 has shown it's a pushover in that case.

Answer (score 6):

First show that
\begin{align}
a_1 a_n \le a_k a_{n-k+1}
\end{align}
for any $k=1,\ldots,n$. By using the assumption that $\{a_n\}$ is an arithmetic sequence with positive terms, it can be easily shown. (Equality holds when $k=1$, $k=n$, or $d=0$, where $d$ is the common difference.)

Then multiplying the above inequalities for $k=1,\ldots,n$, we obtain
\begin{align}
  (a_1 a_n)^n\le (a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^2.
\end{align}
(Note that all terms of $\{a_n\}$ appear twice. For example, $a_2$ appears when $k=2$ and $k=n-1$.)
This completes the proof.